# How to iterate through an array of childItems in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to reference an array of data in one of my pipelines that is being set by a Get Metadata activity. The information is basically all the files in a container that I am trying to write to a SQL table. I am unable to reference the data from the childItems field as every preset expression that is given to me by ADF is not valid.

The only thing that works is if I do the following:
@activity('Get File List').output.childItems[0].name

However, this only returns the first value in the array then it moves on.

How can I iterate through the whole array of childItems?

Answer (score 0):

You can use For Each activity to iterate through the Get meta data activity child items.

Give the Child items array expression to a ForEach after the Get meta data activity like below.

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems
```

[image]

> The information is basically all the files in a container that I am trying to write to a SQL table

Use copy activity inside For Each activity with dataset parameters. Take another source dataset and create a string parameter like below.

[image]

Give this parameter `@dataset().filename` to the file name in the dataset file path. Give your file path till your source folder.

[image]

Now, give this dataset to the copy activity source and give `@item().name` expression as value to the above parameter.

[image]

In the sink, give your SQL dataset. As you want to copy all the files to a single SQL table, you can give your SQL table dataset directly to the copy activity sink.